# how to get USERID when user accept the request Facebook apprequests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, apprequests

i am using facebook apprequests to inviting friends as below

```
      function invitefriends()
{
FB.init({ 
  appId:'XXXXXXX', cookie:true, 
  status:true, xfbml:true 
});

FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
  message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'});

  }
</script>
```

But how get friend id once he accept the request i am able to get below when user accept request
https://apps.facebook.com/XXXXXX/?request_ids=XXXXXXX&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request

from above i can get from userid but how to get userid who accept request

i tried to pass request_ids with redirect_uri but once user install application it get disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Requests documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), whenever a user uses your app to send a request, they are redirect post-send to your app with `?request=REQUEST_ID&to=ARRAY_OF_USER_IDS` appended to the redirect_uri.

So, once you should setup your redirect URI to capture the request ID and the UID array and store it for later.

Then, when the user who received the request accepts it, they'll be directed to a URL similar to the following:

`https://apps.facebook.com/APPNAME/?request_ids=REQUEST_ID&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request`

You can then compare the request_id received here to the request ID you've already stored and then once the user has accepted and dropped onto your App, you'll receive a [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) which you can parse to retrieve their User ID.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, So request_id is different for all user right??

Comment: It depends on whether the sending user chooses more than one friend per request. If there are multiple friends in one request, then the request ID will be the same for all of those friends, and you'll need the signed_request to derive their UID. Alternatively you can force a flow where the user can only pick a single friend at a time.

Comment: No i can't force because i need multiple friend to select so i will get same request ID how can i get this signed_request??

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to, it is pretty clear how to do so.

Comment: From what I can tell, you can only get the user ID once the user has actually signed in to your app.  Meaning, there's no way to tell which user from a multiple friend request is coming to your app through a request link, before they actually sign in.